# Does Safari have issues with ES6 keyword 'let'?

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, let

I've written a web application with `esversion: 6` which works in all browsers (even Edge works!) except Safari 9.

A simple JavaScript snippet like:

```
let m;
```

Causes errors like this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'm'
```

Now, I see Safari is based on Webkit and it should fully support ES6 by now. What's the issue here?

Comment: Safari 10 [support `let`](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#safari10). Have you used `'use strict';`?

Comment: [Safari is 100% ES6 compatible](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) so I would think `let` would be the least of its problems.

Comment: `'use strict';` causes `Unexpected use of reserved workd 'let' in strict mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this link: [Let Keyword Browser Compatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)

As you see in the link, *Safari (9 and lower)* is not supported fully by JavaScript ES6 *let keyword*, despite webkit. But try using [**safari 10.**](https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari) Say, are you using "use strict"? If you are then that might be the problem.

Comment: MDN compatibility tables can trail reality a bit. Use Kangax instead which [shows 100% compatibility with ES6](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: Yes, good point. But I'm discussing different approaches to solve this problem, so if one of them fails; there's backup.

Comment: Yes. That's it, I'm still using Safari 9 which does not support it.

Comment: I'm glad to help.